# Remove Currency Symbol from Magento site

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

How can i remove Currency Symbol from whole site

I am using font icon instead of currency symbol so i want to remove magento default currency symbol from site completely

Answer (score 1):

Magento admin -> system -> manage currency -> symbols

Comment: but we can't make it blank entry

Answer (score 1):

Please use this:

```
Mage::helper('core')->currency($_yourPriceToFormat, false, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento1: Open your admin and go to system > manage currency > symbols. Here you can apply the changes.

Magento2: Open your admin and go to Stores > currency > currency symbols. Here you can apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

In the `Magento admin -> system -> manage currency -> symbols`, you could change the Currency Symbol to anything else, but can't leave it blank, but after my try, I found we could set it as `&nbsp;`, it is the escaped character of the space, then you could set the price css to fix the extra space width, a little trick :)

### Solution 2

Change the codes in theme files which you are using.

Change `Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(), true, false)` to `Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(), false, false)`

Other codes about price could change to without currency too like above.

If you want whole site without currency, you need change all the price codes appear.

Answer (score 0):

**Try not to use object manager**

```
// For specific price
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$currencyManager = $om->get('Magento\Directory\Model\Currency');
$price = $currencyManager->formatPrecision(
    "$5.00",
    4,//precision
    ["display"=>\Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL],
    false
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2 **.4.2**, I believe the price is formatted for displaying (including the currency symbol) in the frontend in **two places**.

One is a function called ‘`formatPrecision`’ in `module-directory/Model/Currency.php`. This function will be called in .phtml (mainly, but not only used in the catalog pages, in `module-catalog/templates/price/amount/default.phtml`).

The other one is a JavaScript function called ‘`formatPrice`’ in `module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-utils.js`, which influence the price display on the product page (the so called ‘pricebox’), cart page and checkout page.

You could create a small extension for changing the output of the format (removing the currency symbol). *You will only need two main files for changing two functions.*

For the first location, a possibility is to create a ‘**before plugin**’ and set/override the **arguments** for the format to hide the symbol like this:

etc/di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency">
        <plugin name="Vendor_ModuleName_Currency_Plugin" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\CurrencyPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin/CurrencyPlugin.php:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin;

use Magento\Directory\Model\Currency;

class CurrencyPlugin
{
    public function beforeFormatPrecision(Currency $subject,
                                                   $price,
                                                   $precision,
                                                   $options = [],
                                                   $includeContainer = true,
                                                   $addBrackets = false)
    {
        $options['display'] = \Magento\Framework\Currency::NO_SYMBOL;

        return [
            $price,
            $precision,
            $options,
            $includeContainer,
            $addBrackets];
    }
}
```

Then, for the Javascript function you can *extend* the ‘formatPrice’ function with a *mixin* like this:

view/frontend/requirejs-config.js:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils': {
                'Vendor_ModuleName/js/price-utils-mixin': true,
            },
        },
    }
};
```

view/frontend/web/js/price-utils-mixin.js:

```
define(['mage/utils/wrapper'], function(wrapper) {
    'use strict';

    return function(target) {

        var newFormatPrice = wrapper.wrap(target.formatPrice, function(original, amount, format, isShowSign) {
            var originalFormat = original(amount, format, isShowSign);
            //change to $, ¥, or ₿
            return originalFormat.replace('€', '').trim();
        });
         
        target.formatPrice = newFormatPrice;

        return target;
    };
});
```

This solution is inspired by https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/323428/67938